# SQL Server table to Excel worksheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

I am trying to pull my SQL Server table into an Excel worksheet. When I use the following VBA code, the current status doesn't filter out to "Bound" accounts.

But when I try not to drop the table like the second VBA code snippet below, then it works. I am using "Drop" since the execution is faster. I am not sure whether I am declaring my Drop table in VBA wrongly in the first code below. Any suggestions/ corrections will be much appreciated.

```
 objMyCmd.CommandText = " IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Step1') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Step1 " & _ 
                         " SELECT a.[RDT_FileID],a.[Master Policy Number], a.[Work item /Submission no#],a.[Insured Name], a.[Credited Office], " & _
                                " a.[Credited Underwriter], a.[Product Line], a.[Product Line Subtype], a.[Current Status], a.[Effective Date], a.[Expiry Date],  a.[Premium in USD $] " & _
                                " FROM  dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a " & _
                                " WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null " & _
                                " AND a.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
                                " AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
                                " AND a.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01' " & _
                                " SELECT * from #Step1 WHERE [Current Status] ='Bound' "
```

The following is my second code for which I am not dropping table, but the process slows down drastically. Any idea on what's wrong on my first code snippet?

```
  objMyCmd.CommandText = " SELECT a.[RDT_FileID],a.[Master Policy Number], a.[Work item /Submission no#],a.[Insured Name], a.[Credited Office], " & _
                                " a.[Credited Underwriter], a.[Product Line], a.[Product Line Subtype], a.[Current Status], a.[Effective Date], a.[Expiry Date],  a.[Premium in USD $] " & _
                                " FROM  dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a " & _
                                " WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null " & _
                                " AND a.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
                                " AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
                                " AND a.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01' " & _
                                " AND a.[Current Status] ='Bound' "
```

Comment: You might want to consider writing this as a stored procedure in SQL Server and just call it from your VBA, rather than trying to hard code a dynamic set of SQL commands.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Writing this entire sql statement in vba will impact the performance ? the table that I call is a view and I dont want it to be stored procedure.

Comment: Using VBA is the worst option when it comes to loading data. Why don' you use Excel's data connections or Power Query? Why are you trying to write such a big query in *Excel*, instead of creating a stored procedure or view in the database. This string is simply unmaintainable

Comment: Yes, writing it all in VBA will make it slower.  A Stored Proc would be more efficient.  If you are open to the idea here is a great article on passing variables from VBA to stored proceedures:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3436/passing-dynamic-query-values-from-excel-to-sql-server/

Comment: @Mitch VBA itself is the problem, not just the query. *Why* use VBA at all when Excel can connect to the database directly?

Comment: That is where you are wrong.  VBA is not always as efficient as a data connection, but if done right can be very nimble.  I pass dynamic variables to stored procs fairly often and they are often nearly as fast as executing them in SSMS directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to sticking with option 1 using the #temp table, try this.  I assumed you were using MS SQL. I added a `Begin` and `End` to your table drop.  Secondly, I don't see where you were inserting the result set into the temp table so added `INTO #Step1` before your FROM statement:

```
objMyCmd.CommandText = "IF (Select object_id('TempDB..#Step1')) IS NOT NULL" & _
" Begin " & _
"   Drop Table #Step1 " & _
" End " & _
 " SELECT a.[RDT_FileID],a.[Master Policy Number], a.[Work item /Submission no#],a.[Insured Name], a.[Credited Office], " & _
                                " a.[Credited Underwriter], a.[Product Line], a.[Product Line Subtype], a.[Current Status], a.[Effective Date], a.[Expiry Date],  a.[Premium in USD $] " & _
                                " INTO #Step1 " &_
                                " FROM  dbo.View_Property_Rater_Of_Record a " & _
                                " WHERE a.[Master Policy Number] Is Not Null " & _
                                " AND a.[RDT_FileID] is null " & _
                                " AND a.[Product Line Subtype] <>  '0102-Marine' " & _
                                " AND a.[Effective Date] >= '2014-04-01' " & _
                                " SELECT * from #Step1 WHERE [Current Status] ='Bound' "
```